# X-UA-Compatible - render page with installed version of IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Does using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" >` (with `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line of the page) ensure the users installed version of IE will be used?

For example, if a person has IE8 installed and I have the above meta tag in my page, will the browser and document mode remain at their currently installed version (Browser Mode: IE8, Document Mode: IE8)?

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work. For instance, when working with intraweb, it seems IE just ignores any headers/meta/doctype, and just goes with IE6(quirks)-mode if it's configured to do so (and I think it by default is). Still, that's luckily only on intraweb-pages.

Comment: @Alxandr - My understanding (based on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) is that the `<!DOCTYPE html>` overrides the default IE _quirks mode_ to _standards mode_.

Comment: @Alxandr - That's not quite correct.  You do have to put the meta tag as the first (or second if you're using a content type meta) for it to be recognized.  It's better to use a header than a metatag though.  And yes, it will override the intranet compatibility settings if you do it correctly.

Comment: @id.ot - yes and no, IE has a compatibility mode setting it uses in the intranet zone that overrides this, unless you use an X-UA-COMPATIBLE header or meta tag.

Comment: @MystereMan You sure? I'm fairly certain we tried everything we could possibly think of, and ended up with the solution to detect IE8 with quirks mode and tell the people using that to turn of the setting.

Comment: @Alxandr - Yes, i'm sure.  But.. as I said.. the meta tag *HAS* to be the first or second meta tag in the list, and only second to the content-type meta, which has to be first if you're using it.  Otherwise it won't work.  That's why it's better to use a custom header instead.

Comment: @MystereMan we did use headers too. Anyways, there's no point in arguing about this, we couldn't get it to work, but that was about 2 years ago I think, so we might not have tries **everything**, at least we thought we did though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the X-UA-Compatible tag is to tell newer versions of IE to render a page in an older mode. For example, if you have IE 9 installed but are using styles that aren't rendering properly in IE 9 but look right in IE 8, you can add the tag to tell IE 9 to render the page using the IE 8 mode.

If you want to tell the browser to render using the most recent version of its rendering engine, use IE=edge.

You can find more information about [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.